# How to declare TypeVar as immutable

Tags: python, types, immutability

In Python, how do I make an immutable/mutable type variable. I have a generic protocol, and some of its methods ought to mutate its inputs of variadic type, while some should not. How do I declare this in my code?

Comment: I don't believe there's any existing way to do that. I can't even think of a way of implementing that that would be practical. The standard library handlesmutability  in the type system by specifying only methods that don't mutate on an ABC like `Mapping`, then putting mutable methods on the inheriting `MutableMapping`. That only works when there's a set of possible methods though.

Comment: Please provide some code to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For immutable data classes you can use:

```
from typing import TypeVar
from dataclasses import dataclass

T = TypeVar('T')

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ImmutableGenericClass:
    value: T

# Example usage:
int_item = ImmutableGenericClass[int](value=1)
str_item = ImmutableGenericClass[str](value="example")
```

For immutability with type hints in general, try:

```
from typing import NamedTuple, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class ImmutableGenericTuple(NamedTuple):
    value: T

# Example usage:
int_item = ImmutableGenericTuple[int](value=1)
str_item = ImmutableGenericTuple[str](value="example")
```